# How would I start this public LFS build project?

Tags: lfs

I had an idea.  I want a box with some simple Linux distro on there.  I want the box to be completely open to anyone.  The idea is, I want to see if a community of online users can build LFS on the box cooperatively.  I want to see how far it can go.

It might end up being a 'count to 10 on 4chan' situation or it may end up being a 'build the Enterprise in Minecraft' situation.  Either way I'd like to see.

My question is, what are the first steps I would need to take to get this project off the ground?  This would be a learning experience for me too.

Comment: This is something that requires root. Having multiple admins work on the same problem, on the same box, at the same time is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am going on a limb here and suggest you shouldn't do this project and don't open the system to anyone because you have to secure your system rigorously but if you still want to do it here are some things you should at least consider:

- Restrict/deny outgoing traffic and have all the source for LFS already in place
- Use something like selinux to secure your system, i.e. no one is allowed to bind to ports, etc.
- Don't allow up/downloads to your system otherwise it may be used for sharing files
- Each user should work on his own system otherwise it will get a mess and user later joining (i.e. only a day later) will have to figure out what the progress is.

Due to this requirements and as you should reboot the system into your LFS to feel rewarded (at least from my point of view) you should consider offering maybe predefined virtual machines where people can build their own LFS system.